# ng-packagr: share code between sub-entries but exclude the shared code from distribution

Tags: angular, ng-packagr

I have an angular library with multiple secondary entry points: `a` and `b`.

I do also have some code which is shared accross `a` and `b`.
The shared code is located in another secondary entry point `shared`.

From my knowledge I must have a secondary entry point for the shared code, otherwise build will fail with a message like `File xxx is not under 'rootDir' xx. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files`.

With this setup the build does succeed. However in my `dist` I find `a`, `b` and `shared`. I don't want that consumers of the lib can use `shared`.

How to exclude it from distribution? Alternatively can I share code between secondary entry points from a source which is not a secondary entry point?